# Draw ASCII frame with given dimensions (x, y) in C

Tags: c

i have a problem to draw a ASCII frame with user given dimensions (x, y).
I have written some code that works for X coordinate, but don't know how to write loop for y dimension.
I will be very grateful for any kind of help.

```
int main() {

    int dimension_1, dimension_2;

    printf("Give first size (x): ");
    scanf("%d", &dimension_1);
    printf("Give second size (y): ");
    scanf("%d", &dimension_2);

    // X
    printf("%c", 201);
    for (int i = 0; i < dimension_1; ++i)
        printf("%c", 205);
    printf("%c", 187);
    // Y !!! HERE DON'T KNOW WHAT TO DO ?
    printf("\n%c", 186);
    printf("%c", 186);
    // X
    printf("\n%c", 200);
    for (int i = 0; i < dimension_1; ++i)
        printf("%c", 205);
    printf("%c", 188);
}
```

Comment: Write a loop that has `dimension_2-2` iterations. The minus 2 is to account for the top and bottom horizontals. Then for each iteration just print whatever you need/want for that row. Also, what do all those magic numbers represent? They don't seem to be valid ascii values.

Comment: that are ascii codes, vertical and horizonal lines like this -> ======.What do you mean by dimension_2-2 loop using while? Can you write this? I don't get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to draw the left side of the box, then add space characters to separate the left from the right side, then draw the right side of the box.

You can do this by writing an outer loop that spans the height of the box and an inner loop that spans the width of the box. The latter adds space characters.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int dimension_x, dimension_y;

    printf("Give first size (x): ");
    scanf("%d", &dimension_x);
    printf("Give second size (y): ");
    scanf("%d", &dimension_y);

    // Draw the top of the box.
    printf("%c", 201);
    for (int x = 0; x < dimension_x; x++)
    {
        printf("%c", 205);
    }
    printf("%c\n", 187);
    
    // Draw the sides of the box.
    for (int y = 0; y < dimension_y; y++)
    {
        // Left side of box.
        printf("%c", 186);

        // Space separating the left and right sides.
        for (int x = 0; x < dimension_x; x++)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }

        // Right side of box.
        printf("%c\n", 186);
    }
    
    // Draw the bottom of the box.
    printf("%c", 200);
    for (int x = 0; x < dimension_x; x++)
    {
        printf("%c", 205);
    }
    printf("%c", 188);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks, it's working. I haven't thought about that type of solution...